# Can't call the function in PHP

Tags: php, function, namespaces

I am having a problem with my index.php. Whenever I go to http://localhost/blog/admin/index.php I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Blog\DB\connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\blog.php on line 6.

In the admin folder all I am requiring is my blog.php which is working fine in other files when I required them. I am stuck with this and can not understand why this is happening.

[index.php in admin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiaUS.png)

My `admin/index.php`:

```
<?php

    require '../blog.php';
```

My blog.php. It is requiring the db.php in which we have called the connect function.

```
<?php

    require 'db.php';

    $conn = \App\DB\connect($config);
    if(!$conn)
        die('Could not connect to db');
```

My db.php. It is just trying to establish a connection:

```
<?php namespace App\DB;

    require 'config.php';

    function connect($config)
    {
        try
        {
            $conn = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blogs",
                              $config['DB_USERNAME'],
                              $config['DB_PASSWORD']);
            $conn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $conn;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your `blog.php` placed inside `http://localhost/blog/`

Comment: Even wider - what's the folder and files structure you have?

Comment: yes my blog.php is placed inside http://localhost/blog/ @Arpita

Comment: @Arpita  .yes my blog.php is placed inside localhost/blog

Comment: @u_mulder I have mentioned the link to the screen shot of the folder. It is at the top. Please open the above link that says - index.php in admin folder